# How to merge Tumblr accounts?

Tags: account-management, tumblr

I have two blogs in [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com), each under its own login name. I'd like to consolidate these two accounts, so that I can manage both blogs from a single account.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not appear possible to transfer a primary blog. (Though you can [transfer a secondary blog to a new primary owner](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/19509/13351).) This is text that used to be found at [a now defunct help page](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/blogs):

> Your primary blog
>
> Your primary blog is the one created
>   when you sign up for Tumblr. It
>   represents you (with its name, link,
>   and avatar) when you follow or like
>   other Tumblr blogs.
>
> ***Switching your primary blog or moving
>   a primary blog to another account are
>   not possible yet.***

Comment: But adding new members works only for secondary blogs: Not the main blog you first started!

Answer (score 2):

**It is not possible to transfer primary blogs**, however you can transfer a secondary blog to a new primary owner. Here's one way:

- Login to the Tumblr account you wish to transfer a blog from.
- From the top menu of the **Dashboard** select the blog you want to transfer. This should load the account controls for that blog on the right hand side of the screen.
- In that list of controls you'll see a button for **Members**. Click it.
- Add the login email for the Tumblr account you want to transfer the blog to and then click **Invite to this blog**.
- Now log out.

After that is done check your email that you just invited. You'll see an email from Tumblr with the subject "**Join**". Click the link in the email to confirm the invite. Now you should see the transferred blog in your blog list. But it's not all yours yet. One more step. Log out of that Tumblr account and log back into the account you're moving the blog from.

Go back to the Dashboard for that blog and click the **Members**. Click **Promote to admin** for the account that you're transferring to, and now click **Leave this blog** for the account your transferring from. All done. That blog is now a secondary blog of a new primary owner.

Thanks to Dan Goodswen, editor of [gocookyourself.com](http://gocookyourself.com/), who [provided some of this information](http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-transfer-a-tumblr-blog-to-a-different-account-holder).

Answer (score 2):

Transferring a primary Tumblr blog to another primary blog is not possible (though [you can transfer a secondary blog to a new primary owner](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/19509/13351)).

I just received this message from a Tumblr support representative:

> Unfortunately, we can’t switch blogs from secondary to primary (or vice versa), nor can we merge accounts, move blogs between accounts, or move posts between blogs.
>
> If you want to move a URL from one blog to another, you can do so by (1) changing the URL of the existing blog to something new so the URL is freed, then (2) changing the URL of a different blog to the freed URL, or creating an entirely new account with the freed URL.
>
> You can always make changes to your URL/username in the Settings area of your blog.
>
> Before you proceed, keep in mind that by changing your URL you will break links to your blog that other people have put in posts, reblogs, and bookmarks. Changing your URL *will not* affect your Followed/Following lists.

This has been the case for a while now. It's unclear if Tumblr has plans make merge possible.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** *This answer is obsolete. Tumblr no longer has a Goodies section and it recently removed RSS import support.*

Tumblr seems to have an export utility in the [Goodies](http://www.tumblr.com/goodies) section (available for Mac OS X only). I am not certain how this export works exactly, so I can't suggest how you might get it back into your blog after that.

You could also consider using the *Import RSS* feature.

1. Go to `www.tumblr.com/customize?redirect_to=http://***YOURACCTHERE***.tumblr.com/`
2. Click *Services* at the top.
3. Fill out the form under the heading "Automatically import my...".

This doesn't "merge the blogs", but you'll end up with content from both, and you can just stop using the other one.

Comment: Good workaround, although it doesn't really achieve what I wanted. +1

Comment: "Goodies" has been renamed "apps", and this export utility is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You can try contacting tumblr support by emailing **support@tumblr.com**, tell them what you want, I believe they do this kind of things.

Comment: Have you ever emailed Tumblr's support and found that they actually did this sort of one-off thing? I guess I'm curious b/c I have, and they didn't help me at all :(

Comment: Tumblr support will not help you merge primary blogs. See my answer [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67963/13351).

Answer (score 0):

The Tumblr backup exports your posts in directories. Images are in one folder and posts are in HTML in another folder.

To merge two Tumblr blogs, I had to copy the text form the exported HTML files and create a new post on my new Tumblr blog and add the photo that was also exported.

Answer (score -3):

Make your primary blog a secondary blog in settings

Comment: Is this not possible? I guess that explains the downvotes?